# Move image from resources to a folder in C

Tags: c, image

I've added a jpg picture to the resource folder in visual studio, lets name it `dog.jpg` and now i want to move it to a specified folder like `c:\hi` to the disk running this code..

How can I accomplish that in **C** language?
I've searched a lot and all the answers are in c++\c# :/

Thanks!

Comment: At least *some* of the C++ programs you find should be able to give you the basic principles: Extract the data, save it to disk. Even if the "saving to disk" part is a little different in C++, if the C++ program uses the Windows API functions to extract the resource data then you should easily be able to handle the saving using standard C functions.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to clarify what you mean by "resource folder"? Do you mean a folder or directory on disk? Or do you mean the resources that are compiled and linked with the executable?

Comment: in VS, resource files, that when i'll compile this code this picture will be added to the excecutable

Comment: Then I suggest you look into [`LoadResource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`LockResource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`SizeofResource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648048%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). These should have been easy to find yourself with a little searching.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Windows API [MoveFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239(v=vs.85).aspx) or [MoveFileEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240(v=vs.85).aspx) on Windows.

Comment: can you please write me the syntax? how to access the picture from rsc and place it in the folder?

Comment: @MiriAdj it's a simple C function call with two parameters, the path to the source file and the path to the target file.